# WatchOS How to keep to get acceleration data

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos

I'm writing independent watchOS app. I'd like to keep app turn on & getting acceleration data, but app go sleep & don't get data shortly.

I think it might be hard to keep getting data according to my sources, so I use remote-notification & try to get data as much as possible. Is there anything better way to get more data or keep getting data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by making workout session. it can keep to get acceleration data while workout.